# how to run htmlentities() through specifically one attribute of every row of output array

Tags: php, javascript, sql, parsing, sanitization

Right now I am trying to run one attribute/"column" of every row ("record"/object) in an array through the htmlentities() function. Since only that attribute/column contains a string that will be outputted in the DOM html.

However, I am fetching the desired rows and putting them all in an array, then JSON encoding the array and sending the entire ray over. Like so:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pointers WHERE `public` = 1;");

$rows = array();

while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
      $rows[] = $r;
  }

echo json_encode($rows);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Example of what my table looks like

```
+------+------+------+------+
|key   |attr1 |attr2 | attr3|
+------+------+------+------+
|1     |  int |string|  int |
+------+------+------+------+
|2     |  int |string|  int | 
+------+------+------+------+
|...   |  ... |  ... |  ... |
+------+------+------+------+
```

Attr2 is the only column storing strings.

**I am wondering how I can run htmlentities() through that attr2, for each row that is selected.**

I tried just htmlencode-ing everything:

```
echo json_encode(htmlencode($rows));
```

But then my output did not display...

Also, **is there a method equivalent to htmlencode() client-side, in javascript/jQuery** after I have received the rows/records? Because currently I can easily access the specific string of each row/record using something like this `dataResponse.attr2`

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you shouldn't use `htmlentities` either way (unless you have a good reason to do so), but just use `htmlspecialchars()`. When you should do this is when constructing the array with the elements:

```
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $r['attr2'] = htmlspecialchars($r['attr2'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $rows[] = $r;
}
```

However if you are going to simply use this data to send to the client side to be processed / added to the DOM using javascript I would just use `.createTextNode()`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. And thank you for your extra suggestion!  Basically, I didn't want the user to be able to insert html tags into their strings, such as `<span class="button"> sometext </span>`, because if the user decided to do so, the html would not appear with the text and the class effects would be applied. Instead I wanted all special characters to simply appear as they are. However both htmlspecialchars() -- your method -- and htmlentities() seemed to have the same effect. Could you quickly explain what is the key difference for your suggestion to use specialchars?

Comment: `htmlentities()` converts *all* characters for which there are HTML entities where as `htmlspecialchars()` only converts the most likely unsafe characters. So your `htmlentities` converted strings will be *much* heavier (and often it is just not needed).

Answer (score 1):

Encode it as you read it from the result set:

```
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $rows[] = $r;
    $rows[2] = htmlentities($rows[2]);
  }
```